# How to increase performance of a Spark submit job when dealing with huge data sets?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have some 100 files(CSV files compressed in .GZ format) on my HDFS Dir and each files has almost 100K records, while I am trying to read records and assigning to df, it is reading file by file and taking more than hour to process those 100 files.
I have tried different approaches like submiting in yarn mode and increasing memory none of them made it increase in performance?.

```
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --driver-memory 15G \
  --executor-memory 10G \
  --num-executors 8 \
  --executor-cores 8
```

Can someone help me how to deal with this?

Comment: Your performance may be IO bound

Comment: Are you reading xml, json or such ? https://szczeles.github.io/Reading-JSON-CSV-and-XML-files-efficiently-in-Apache-Spark/

Comment: this are csv but they are in .gz format

Comment: Show us how you read the data, please.

Comment: val data = sc.textFile("/path/*", 100)
val wc = data.map(line => line.split(",")).map(row => new ClassDf(row(0), row(1)))    val df = wc.toDF
    df.write.format("orc").save(/path/)

Comment: Why do you set number of partitions in `textFile()`? Spark can do it automatically and it will not require re-partitioning right at the start. Btw, you could add your code to question, not as a comment